# Number of Generators of [G,G] when G is free?

Tags: gr.group-theory

If $G$ is a free group on $n>1$ generators, then $[G,G]$ is also free, being a subgroup of a free group.  Is there a formula for the number of generators of this free group in terms of n?

Comment: Yes, it's infinite. 

Comment: It's infinite. One way to see this is to write down the corresponding covering space of the wedge of $n$ circles and note that it is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of infinitely many circles. 

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/74902/free-group-of-finite-rank-can-contain-free-groups-of-infinite-rank-as-a-subgroup/74905#74905